# Can't receive WhatsApp message notifications via webhook

Tags: api, facebook, whatsapp

I set up a glitch service as described [in the Meta doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/sample-app-endpoints/) to receive notifications of WhatsApp received messages via a webhook. However, [messages](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/whatsapp_business_account/#messages) notifications are not received at all, not even pressing the test button of the webhook. Please, note that it's not a general configuration problem, since other notifications (e.g., [account_alerts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/whatsapp_business_account/#account_alerts)) are properly received.

(I'm using the test phone number provided by Meta)

Any hints about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/856675538926230/

(Now it seems fixed)